# How can I pass `this` context to a self invoking anonymous function without storing `this` in a variable?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, self-invoking-function

Ideally we can do this using the `Function.prototype.bind` function. I don't think there's a clear way to use a fat arrow function here either. Ycombinator magic?

This is what I tried so far:

```
(function pump () {
  return browserReadableStreamReader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
    if (done) {
      return this.end()
    }

    this.write(value)
    return pump()
  })
}).bind(this)()
```

Comment: Instead of using `bind` then invoking the function right away, just use `call` instead: `(...).call(this)`

Comment: ... also, are you able to declare a variable right before the IIFE? If so then an arrow function is possible.

Comment: `(() => { ... your code ...})()` - `this` will be the same as `this` you bind to in your code - check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez8gysj9/) - so, yes, you clearly **can** use the so called ***fat** arrow function* - or as it's called in javascript, the *arrow function* (whose physical appearance is not spoken about)

Comment: Is the code not working as expected or you want a more elegant solution?

Comment: The code was not working. I ended up making a class extending PassThrough, then calling it in the constructor as an instance method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')
/**
 * Google Chrome ReadableStream PassThrough implementation
 * @extends PassThrough
 */
class BrowserPassThrough extends PassThrough {
  /**
   * @param {Object} options - options to pass to PassThrough
   * @param {ReadableStreamDefaultReader} browserReadableStreamReader - reader
   */
  constructor (options, browserReadableStreamReader) {
    super(options)
    this.reader = browserReadableStreamReader
    this.pump()
  }

  pump () {
    this.reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
      if (done) {
        return this.end()
      }

      this.write(value)
      this.pump()
    })
  }
}
module.exports = BrowserPassThrough
```